# expect garbage before prompt

Tags: tcl, expect, garbage

I try to connect to my router using ssh in order to automatically extract some logs from it.

I developed this code below :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh root@192.168.1.1
expect "Are you sure you want to"
send -- "yes\r"
expect "password"
send -- "root\r"
expect "\#"
send -- "ls\r"
expect "\#"
```

the problem is I expected a garbage before the prompt in the output log.

```
spawn ssh root@192.168.1.1
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:6aeE74qXMeQzg0SGJBZMIa0HFQ5HJrNqE5f3XZ6Irds.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/amin/.ssh/known_hosts).

root@192.168.1.1's password: 


BusyBox v1.30.1 () built-in shell (ash)


OpenWrt Version: ALPHA
OpenWrt base: 19.07
------------------------------------
]0;root@openwrt: ~root@openwrt:~# ls
[0;0mnetwork[m
]0;root@openwrt: ~root@openwrt:~#
```

what's the main cause of this issue? How I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe an escaped EOF...

Comment: Btw I would use SSH authentication instead of storing passwords...

Comment: Those could also be ANSI Color codes if I look a more closely...

Comment: @dan1st How I can remove them?

Comment: What about https://superuser.com/a/380778/1079262?

Comment: You can also use `spawn ssh -t root@192.168.1.1 'bash --norc'`.

Comment: @dan1st Piping through a filter won't work with expect, which is doing stuff with virtual terminal emulation under the covers. Even putting a non-buffered `cat` on the remote end will probably go wonky due to the changes it tends to cause to buffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are terminal escape sequences being issued, *probably* to control what colour the terminal uses. The easiest fix is to set the terminal type (an environment variable) to something that doesn't support colour *before doing the `spawn`.* Perhaps this will do the trick:

```tcl
set env(TERM) "dumb"
```

If that doesn't work (it depends on exactly what is in someone's `.bashrc`) then you can just override the `PS1` environment variable on the remote side with your first command *after logging in.*

```
# etc for logging in
expect "# "
send "PS1='# '\r"
expect "# "
# Everything should be right from here on
```

Comment: I added this line : set env(TERM) "dumb" and It works well. Thanks.